# connecting one signal to multiple slots qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I am trying to connect two slots with on signal. here is my header file where I have defined my signals

```
class loginChecker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
static loginChecker *instance(void);
signals:
void loginid();
void loginemail();

 private:
loginChecker(void) {}
~loginChecker(void) {}

 private:
static loginChecker *s_instance;
```

};

it is sigalton class. here is my slot which is another signalton class named as loginProcess
the slot name in this class in `getUserData(QString& userData)`

in The loginChecker.cpp 
I am trying to connect these declared signals with  `getUserData(QString userData)` slot

```
    loginProcess *lp;
   lp = loginProcess::instance();
```

here I am accessing instance of loginProcess signalton class which has slot

These are two ways I am trying to connect these signal and slot but none are working

```
     QObject::connect(s_instance, SIGNAL(loginid()), es, SLOT(getUserData(userid)));
```

this is throwing no such slot error at runtime

```
    `QObject::connect(s_instance, &esCoreAuthenticator::loginid, es, &loginProcess::getUserData(uid));`
```

this is thworing this error `cannot call member function 'void loginProcess::getUserData(const QString&)' without object` at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Since your signal has no arguments you can't connect it to slot which has some.

And also it seems to me that in first case you should try `SLOT(getUserData(QString&))` and in second case just `&loginProcess::getUserData` without any parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks it seems like second one is working, but I do not understand that how getUserData will get the value of user_id if I do not pass argument in it...

Comment: @user3290805 Pass it in your signal: `signals:
void loginid(const QString &id);`. Then you emit it like `emit loginid(user_id)` or whatever you use for your `user_id`. You could also use [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html).

Comment: Yes my advice was not to remove it from slot but rather to add it to signal if you need to pass it.